# How to take each item of array1 combine item array 2 to new array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, associative-array, array-merge

I have a difficult situation.
I will have an array like

```
array(
    'title' => array(
        "ABC",
        "DEF",
        "GHI"
    ),
    "url" => array(
        "abc",
        "def",
        "ghi"
    )
);
```

Now, I want to create new array with data like:

```
array(
    array(
        "title" => "ABC",
        "url" => "abc",
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "DEF",
        "url" => "def",
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "GHI",
        "url" => "ghi",
    ),
);
```

I did by foreach loop but in fact, I have more than 10 arrays. I will be decrease the performance if I create 10 foreach loops for each of them.

So my question is:

- Does it have any function in PHP can do that or we have to do it by ourself?

Thank for your reading and answering.

Comment: Since there's no common data, I'd say it might be easier just to do it yourself.

Comment: Use simple `foreach()`

Comment: @aynber I did it but I just ask for a best way to do that than foreach. Because I have more than 02 arrays like example. I have to do 10 times foreach loop. It will be affect the performance.

Comment: @TommyDo try my answer, it should work as you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work dynamic with any number of subarrays in your main array.
It uses array_keys to find all the subarrays.

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$count = count($arr[$keys[0]]);

For($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
    Foreach($keys as $key){
        $res[$i][$key] = $arr[$key][$i];
    }
}

Var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/41PNh

Example with three subarrays: https://3v4l.org/5SmSW

Answer (score 4):

You need to use simple `foreach()`

```
$final_array = [];

foreach($array['title'] as $key=>$value){
    $final_array[] = ['title'=>$value,'url'=>$array['url'][$key]];
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/999434

Comment: This will not work, OP updated his requirement in comments above

Comment: I gave answer 10 min back when OP change his requirement. And now you gave answer

Comment: I know, just thought I should mention it.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to convert array to expected array?

Yes.

Does it have any function in PHP can do that or we have to do it by ourself?

No.

You should loop over both arrays using a for loop to construct the array you want.

**Example:**

```
$array = ["a", "b"];
$array2 = ["b", "c"];

$newArray = [];

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    $newArray[$key] = [];
    $newArray[$key]["title"] = $value;
}

foreach ($array2 as $key => $value)
{
    $newArray[$key]["url"] = $value;
}


var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: Thank for quick respons. I did same your result but in fact I have more than 2 array "title", "url". May be 10 arrays. So with this way, I have to do 10 foreach loop for that. I just worry about the performance.